# Dynamically set the path in immutable.js setIn([]) function

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have an immutable object:

```
let mutableObject = {
  test: 
     { test2: { a:1, b:2, c:3 } }
};
```

I need to use setIn() function to set a value inside test2 object. But in this scenario i have to set it dynamically using values from an array.

```
let keys = ['test', 'test2'];
```

I tried setting the value like this :

```
let immutableObj = fromJS(mutableObject).setIn(keys, [1, 2]);
```

which is not working.

The output should be:

```
{
  test: { 
    test2 : [1, 2]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is good. You just need to convert to a regular JS object if you want that output. You can use the `.toJS()` method for this. Like so:

`let immutableObj = fromJS(mutableObject).setIn(keys, [1, 2]).toJS();`